# Facebook Share thumbnails not working

Tags: image, facebook, share

I have added all facebook meta tag details in my page but still it doesn't take the image with link share on facebook

[This](http://www.pyromaniac.com/op_eds/brandon-i-told-you-so-lloyd-player-profile-2011) is my url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chirag, i ran your link through the url Linter http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pyromaniac.com%2Fop_eds%2Fbrandon-i-told-you-so-lloyd-player-profile-2011

Every thing looks fine there, it can take upto 24 hours for Facebook to recache your page information after you have made changes to the meta tags.  You can force this update by running the url though the debug tool. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Ok , Thanks Shawn,I will wait for 24 hrs and let see that this works or not